# How to set session timeout in Struts2?

Tags: session, struts2, session-cookies, session-variables, struts

How to set session timeout in Struts 2:

```java
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;

public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
      public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
          Map<String,Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
          if(session.isEmpty())
              return "session";
          return invocation.invoke();
      }
}
```

it's not working.

Comment: In web.xml (likely preferred) or using HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval like most other Java web frameworks? I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work" since there's no code here that checks for session validity.

Answer (score 0):

This code you can use in interceptor:

```java
HttpServletSession httpsession = invocation.getInvocationContext().getServletRequest().getSession();
httpsession.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout);
```

---

You can read more about setting a timeout to http session:

> [**Difference between setting session timeouts using `web.xml` and `setMaxInactiveInterval`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184382/573032)
>
> The first approach is using a static constant in the configuration for all sessions. The second approach is dynamic where you can set the value using servlet API at runtime dynamically and affected only a session which method is called. Once the value is set the session is invalidated by the container regardless which approach is used. See what the doc says about `HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`:
>
> > Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.
>
> An interval value of zero or less indicates that the session should never timeout.
>
> The value in deployment descriptor `web.xml` is in “minutes”, but the `setMaxInactiveInterval()` method accepts the value in “seconds”.